# PHP: Two buddy classes want to share methods, but only with each other -- Am I Doing It Wrong?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have two classes, which are good friends together, and each has a method that the other needs to use. I don't want to just expose the methods publicly, which is so far all I've been able to do.

I thought this was the whole purpose of `protected`, but that only exposes methods to parent or child classes -- my two classes are merely good pals, and a righteous team.

***Why are these classes such long-time buddies?***

Well, you see, I have an `Item` class, and a `Selection` class. Items have a string label. Selections are groups of Items, though, not all Items have to be in a Selection (Items can be standalone). Selection extends ArrayObject, so that it can store the items internally, like a cool associative array (easy item access with `$selection["label"]`).

When you change an Item object's `label`, the Selection assoc-array's key needs to be updated to match!

So, when an Item is added to a Selection, the Selection object calls the `associate` method on that Item, which tells the Item who it's daddy is.

Then, whenever the Item's label is changed -- the Item calls the `updateKey` method on its associated daddy Selection object.

This way, the Items, their labels, and the Selections they live in together, can all coexist in peaceful harmony :)

Anyways, the problem is that my solution seems to require that these two precious methods, `associate` and `updateKey`, be exposed to the public.

I've cooked up the following demo code, to explain my little Item-Selection team.

```
<?php

class Item {

    private $label;
    private $selection;

    function __construct ($label) {
        $this->label($label);
    }

    function label ($label=null) {
        if (!$label) return $this->label;
        if ($this->selection) $this->selection->updateKey($this->label, $label);
        $this->label = $label;
        return $this;
    }

    public function associate ($selection=null) {
        $this->selection = $selection;
        return $this;
    }

}

class Selection extends ArrayObject {

    public function updateKey ($old, $new) {
        $this[$new] = $this[$old];
        unset($this[$old]);
        return $this;
    }

    function add () {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $argi => $arg) {
            if ($arg instanceof Item) $this[$arg->label()] = $arg->associate($this);
            else throw new Exception("invalid type for selection->add");
        }
        return $this;
    }

    function item ($label) {
        return $this->add( new Item($label) );
    }

}

$selection = (new Selection)
    ->item("A")
    ->item("B");

$selection->add( new Item("C") );

$selection["A"]->label("APPLE");
$selection["B"]->label("BANANA");
$selection["C"]->label("CRANBERRY");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($selection);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

***How can I stop `associate` and `updateKey` from being exposed to the public?***

At first, I tried to see if there way a way I could have these two classes inherit from a greater class, hoping that maybe this would make them related enough to share protected methods -- however, Selection already extends ArrayObject, and PHP doesn't allow multiple inheritance. What can one do?

How should I refactor this?

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't really make these methods only avaliable for each other, what you can do it to make updateKey more like an event, something like onLabelChange($label).
That way you are not actually exposing Selection's implementation by saing:

"Hey Selection, update your key because I changed a label",

this approach is more like:

"Hey Selection, I updated a label, so, do your busines, wharever it is".

In that case you need to do some more checking to make sure that $label is contained within Selection's object.

**EDIT:** I've literally just now found this thing called [Traits](https://www.php.net/traits) tha were introduced in PHP 5.4, I don't know them very much (I just read them on php.net) but thay may solve your dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not have a concept of friendship relationship like C++ so no go there. However, there is really no reason you need to hide these methods that I can see. In fact they seem to be designed to be public. Perhaps what you need to do is guard these methods and make sure they operate consistently when manipulated by something other than themselves.

- Since "Items can be standalone" you probably want `Items` to be able to be associated and re-associated with `Selections`, so `associate()` should be public.
- add a check to `updateKey()` to ensure the items that is being updated is an instance of Item, and is a member of the given Selection.
- You need disassociate() method. Add a membership test to that too. Make sure the items disassociate themselves appropriately when manipulated via the public interface.

If your question is simply "How can implement friendship in PHP" see [Is there a simple way to emulate friendship in php 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938858/is-there-a-simple-way-to-emulate-friendship-in-php-5-3). In general you can hack it up but it is generally not worth it.